# Firebase MultiSelect Delete from ListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am currently pulling data from Firebase and putting it in a list view and all that is working fine.

The app is a deciding wheel and I need to let the users add and delete some of the choices based on their personal preference.

They will be able to select multiple items in the list view and then delete those all at once. I have not found any way to do this online that made any sense to me at all.

```
public class RestaurantSelectionList extends Fragment {

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mRestReference = mRootRef.child("restaurants");

List<String>listofrest = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView restaurantListView;
ListAdapter restaurantListAdapter;



public RestaurantSelectionList(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_selection_list_frag,container,false);
    restaurantListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurantListView);

    restaurantListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Restaurants>(getActivity(),Restaurants.class,R.layout.individual_restaurant_name,mRestReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Restaurants model, int position) {
            TextView restName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restname);
            restName.setText(model.getName());


            listofrest.add(position,model.getName());

        }
    };

    restaurantListView.setAdapter(restaurantListAdapter);
    restaurantListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    restaurantListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);


    restaurantListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

 }
```

This is where I have my list view and I was wondering if this could even be done with Firebase? This is the first time I have ever worked with Firebase and it has caused me a lot of problems so far. This is the list that is shown:

[image: List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would `setOnClickListener` to the check box.
Initialize a global `hashMap()`. When a item is checked, put that item ID in the `hashMap()`, if unchecked remove the item ID from the `hashMap()`. Then take the reference of the node u want to update, execute `updateChildren()` method, setting the correspond Item ID's value to `null`.